# Picking Number String out of Text String

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a text field which has entries of variable length of the form:

```
"house:app.apx&resultid=1234,clientip"
```

or

```
"tost:app.apx&resultid=123,clientip"
```

or

```
"airplane:app.apx&resultid=123489,clientip"
```

I'm trying to pick out the numbers between `resultid='...',clientip` no matter what the rest of the string looks like.  So in this example it would be the numbers:

```
1234
123
12389
```

the part of the string of the form `resultid='...',clientip` always stays the same except the length of the number can vary.

Comment: Use `substring` together with `charindex`.

Comment: Is this data you are retrieving from the database or are you trying to do this in a stored procedure within the database?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
-- test data
DECLARE @t table (String VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @t VALUES 
('"house:app.apx&resultid=1234,clientip"'),
('"tost:app.apx&resultid=123,clientip"'),
('"airplane:app.apx&resultid=123489,clientip"')


SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(
    String, 
    CHARINDEX('resultid=', String) + 9, 
    CHARINDEX(',clientip', String) - CHARINDEX('resultid=', String) - 9
  ) 
FROM @t

-- Result
1234
123
123489
```

You might want to add some kind of check so that you don't process null values.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like below using string functions

```
select SUBSTRING("house:app.apx&resultid=1234,clientip",
                           CHARINDEX('=',"house:app.apx&resultid=1234,clientip"),
                           CHARINDEX(',',"house:app.apx&resultid=1234,clientip") - CHARINDEX('=',"house:app.apx&resultid=1234,clientip"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Rahul but somewhat different and using PATINDEX:

```
declare @start varchar(20) = '%resultid=%'
declare @end varchar(20) = '%,clientid%'
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Field,PATINDEX(@start,Field)),@start,''),@end,'')
```